# Initialization of a constant reference with a number

Tags: c++, reference, constants, rvalue-reference

What is the meaning of the following line? Why is this allowed as 0 is an r-value and not a variable name? What is the significance of `const` in this statement?

```
const int &x = 0;
```

Answer (score 72):

A non-const reference cannot point to a literal. You cannot bind a literal to a reference to non-const (because modifying the value of a literal is not an operation that makes sense) and only l-values can be bound to references to non-const. You can however bind a literal to a reference to const.

The "const" is important. In this case, a temporary variable is created for this purpose and it's usually created on stack.

Comment: Are you sure that the “temporary variable” is created on the stack? I would have expected that `x` is pointing to some area in the data segment. Similar how string literals work. If `x` points onto the stack, the reference could become invalid too early. For example, if you pass the reference as a pointer to some static variable and leave the method. Besides that, if every call of the method would create a new “temporary variable”, I think we wouldn't need to use `const`. I think `const` is necessary because the memory area is reused between function calls.